# Class loading eclipse rcp

Tags: eclipse, classloader, rcp

I have an eclipse rcp application. This application will try to load class files from a directory outside the application. However I always get an error of ClassNotFoundException. Do you have any ideas how class loading works in eclipse rcp?

Basically the use case is

1. Read an xml file - done
2. Put those xml data in Navigator - done
3. When user clicks on data in navigator, locate the class in a directory and try to load it - classnotfoundexception

I created a test java project and i added the external class library and it can locate those successfully. However if i intergrate it in eclipse rcp, it throws that error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse RCP applications use the OSGi class loading support to find the class loader associated with the OSGi bundles (plugins) in your application. If you want to load a class from somewhere, then you need to make a `ClassLoader` that can load a class from a directory (perhaps use the `URLClassLoader`). So you will need to create one of these and use it to load the class from the desired location.

Comment: Thanks. I was using the old ClassLoader, should have used URLClassLoader.

Comment: Problem now is that when using the code below, there is no annotation present. The class im loading is just a JUnit4 TestSuite.

    URL classUrl;
    classUrl = testSuiteDir.toURI().toURL();

    URL[] classUrls = { classUrl };
    URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(classUrls);

    Class<?> cls = ucl.loadClass(clazz.getClassName());
  
    if (cls.isAnnotationPresent(SuiteClasses.class)) {
 System.out.println("true");
    } else {
 System.out.println("false");
    }